# Помогите запретить <p> вылезать за рамки и при выходе ставить ... (html,css)

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

введите сюда описание изображения
на некрасивую линию прошу не обращать внимание. Как видно если текста больше чем надо, он вылазиет за рамки. НУжно что бы он просто ставил ... и обрезался.
это тег p который находится в блоке. Весь нижний текст "Вы: Много текста..." это границы блока. Через overflow: hiiden с границами он просто обрезает. А нужно ставить ... . Пробовал по количеству символов обрезку делать, не выходит если в сообщении есть перенос строки

Comment: В CSS это работает только для однострочного текста. Устроит?

Comment: Да, но elipsis пробовал, не работает)

Comment: ```white-space: nowrap; /* Запрещаем перенос строк */
overflow: hidden; /* Обрезаем все, что не помещается в область */
text-overflow: ellipsis; /* Добавляем многоточие */```

Comment: посмотрите тут http://htmlbook.ru/css/text-overflow

Comment: @DmitryDevelop, все работает, просто вам нужно запретить перенос.

Comment: Aleksandr, это для p или для блока???

Comment: @DmitryDevelop, для `p`

Comment: @Andrey Fedorov, нет, я добавил скрины в вопрос, посомтрите пожалуйста

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, аопрос закрыт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  margin: auto 0;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris efficitur tincidunt mollis. Aliquam ullamcorper mi ullamcorper risus eleifend, sit amet mattis augue consequat. Quisque nec urna vestibulum, facilisis felis id, auctor lacus. Cras sodales
  sit amet sem convallis lobortis. Curabitur gravida neque orci, et tempor dolor sagittis a. Pellentesque maximus volutpat luctus. Nulla ullamcorper, magna vel scelerisque tincidunt, dui ligula sollicitudin tellus, vitae iaculis purus urna a libero. Nunc
  ut tempor neque, in mattis lorem. Curabitur in pulvinar lorem. Aliquam vehicula metus vel enim vehicula molestie.
</p>
```